# How to read log files from Tamper Data Firefox add-on?

Tags: web-application

I have a few log files of request\response for web application and I need to analyze it somehow.

The log files have been made with the Tamper Data Firefox add-on, but I can't find any way to use that add-on to read its own logs. It's simple XML files but it's kind of impossible to work with it just like that since there are over 150 request\response operations in it.

Is there any software to read these files?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any software dedicated for reading Tamper Data files. There is a [python script to do this](http://randomizedcode.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/TDParser/) but I've never used it, I don't even know if it's working.

All the most popular languages have their own xml parsing libraries so writing something by yourself should be rather easy, and this is the solution I would go for.

Another thing is what do you want to achieve and do you really need Tamper Data for that? You could switch to Firebug (Net panel) with Netexport add-on. That would make possible for you to save traffic in HAR file. You would basically get the same data (and even more) and there are dedicated HAR parsers / analyzers you could use. Another solution is to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer

- I remember during my testing we used firefox add on for simulating GZIP, tamper data
- I would suggest to write custom code to parse and extract required content